Terminal crashes when running command to install Spike and Verilator
Everytime I run the command to install custom spike and Verilator, my terminal crashes. I can't seem to make it work. Below are the commands I am running:
export DV_SIMULATORS=veri-testharness,spike
bash verif/regress/smoke-tests.sh

I am trying to synthesize the cva6 from openHW in the below link:
CVA6 RISC-V CPU

Use bash's -x option to see what's going on in the script:  bash -x verif/regress/smoke-tests.sh |& tee oops.log
